# How to get the progress of a downloaded ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I know that there has been other threads on this, but i still find it hard to understand all aspects of this problem.

I am working on a web app that uses Ajax quite a lot (with jQuery and PHP). Everything works fine, though I would like to show a progress bar at the top - kinda like youtube (see the red loader at the top of the window when loading content). I have seen a lot of suggestions using the xhr object to handle this - but this requires the requested page has a header with a content length. Since all my pages a loaded dynamically with different amounts of contents depending on the url, i find it hard to set this header appropriately.

So if i set up code like this:

```
    (function($, window, undefined) {
    //is onprogress supported by browser?
    var hasOnProgress = ("onprogress" in $.ajaxSettings.xhr());

    //If not supported, do nothing
    if (!hasOnProgress) {
        return;
    }

    //patch ajax settings to call a progress callback
    var oldXHR = $.ajaxSettings.xhr;
    $.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
        var xhr = oldXHR();
        if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr.addEventListener('progress', this.progress, false);
        }

        if(xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.progress, false);
        }

        return xhr;
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

and

```
$.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        success: function(result) {

                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('ajax failure');
                        },
                         progress: function(e) {
                            if(e.lengthComputable) {
                                var pct = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                                // do something - like change a progressbar
                            } else {
                                console.warn('Content Length not reported!');
                            }
                        },

                    });
```

It will result in the console warn, since the browser doesn't know how big the file is before the whole thing is already loaded.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this? Id be very interested in in-depth tutorials on this too, as I can't really find any that explains whats going on with xhr object through the code above either.

Note: im not interested in setting up spinners and loaded on normal ajax events. Im interested in being able to get the percentage of the load of the requested file.

Thank you so much.